# Match the string using inputs regex

Tags: regex

I have a column which has values like :

```
col1
ABB
CDD
EFF
GHH
IJJ
KLL
```

If I input A,D then it should return

```
ABB
CDD
```

On inputing J,K it should return

```
IJJ
KLL
```

I'm trying to do this using `Regex`

Comment: What regex tool/flavor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use regex, remove commas, and add square brackets outside the input to construct a search expression:

```
A,D ---> [AD]
J,K ---> [JK]
```

If this expression matches anywhere in the string from your list, add the matched string to the output.